# Cannot start SQL SERVER SERVICE in Windows Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, windows

This morning this problem occurs when my co-worker says they cannot connect to `database`.

I've checked the server and found that the `SQL SERVER SERVICE` is currently stopped. The problem is I cannot start it manually I've also tried to start the service in `services.msc` and there's still no luck.

We are using `SQL SERVER 2000 ENTERPRISE EDITION`
Here the screencaps:

[image]

[image]

Heres the what it says in the Event Logs

```
SQL Server is aborting. Fatal exception c0000005 caught.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the version of SQL Server you are running, however, are you up-to-date with updates?  There have been fixes for Access Violations in SQL Server that you may not have at this time.

Here is an MSDN post that has some relevance (though it is specific to SQL 2008):
[sql server 2008 is terminating because of fatal exception c0000005](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/ea05a4e1-dfea-4293-ac45-85a9ea949832/)

Access Violations occur because the application has attempted to access memory areas that it doesn't own.  That is a problem with code.  And quite often there are service packs or updates that address these issues.

Without knowing exactly which version of SQL Server you are running a more specific fix cannot be suggested.

Answer (score 1):

That's a permissions problem.  Odds are the SQL Server doesn't have access to the database files or the LOG folder.

Check the NTFS permissions on the files/folders that the SQL Server needs to use. The Account which is running the SQL Server needs to have Modify permissions at the minimum on the LOG and DATA folders as well as the files